# Workaround for Enum data types for PostgreSQL Google Cloud Datastream

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cdc, google-datastream

I was surprised to find that Cloud Datastream does not support [enum data types](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/sources-postgresql#postgresqlknownlimitations)  in source if replicating from PostgreSQL.

> Datastream doesn't support replication of columns of the enumerated (ENUM) data type.

As we have quite a few fields created that way, that is not a viable option for us. Is any good workaround for this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256041029):

> A workaround is to create a generated column which is of type text. DataStream will then sync the text column automatically and happily.

Also:

> we're looking into adding support for ENUMs as part of our GA launch of the PostgreSQL source